# Buffering Emails for Faster Access: Microsoft Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

At my workplace, I have Microsoft Outlook as my email client (India) and Microsoft Exchange Server(USA) in the backend. Now I want that Outlook should keep on buffering my emails on my local system after a fixed amount of time.

Right now, it seems to me that it fetches data on when I perform some operation like reading an unread mail, which make it too slow to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use "Cached Exchange Mode".  Open the "Account Settings" window (how to get there varies widely depending on the version of Outlook you're using), select your Exchange account and click the "Change" button.  On the window that comes up, you should see a checkbox for "Use Cached Exchange Mode".  Enable that option and proceed through the rest of the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Exchange Cached mode.  See:

- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/turn-on-or-off-cached-exchange-mode-HP001232935.aspx
- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/CH001004599.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179175.aspx